# reshaping of dataframe in r

Tags: r, reshape

I want to reshape a dataframe in R and I know, that the reshape function or melt should do the trick,
but I cant figure out how to write the code correctly

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  X       date tim eric
1 a 2022-02-02   1    2
2 b 2022-02-02   3    4
3 a 2022-03-03   5    6
4 b 2022-03-03   7    8
```

```
a <- data.frame(X = rep(c("a","b"), 2),
                date = c(rep("2022-02-02",2), rep("2022-03-03",2)),
                tim = c(1,3,5,7),
                eric = c(2,4,6,8)
                )
```

and i want to have the shape like this:

```
     x       date a b
1  tim 2022-02-02 1 3
2 eric 2022-03-03 2 4
3  tim 2022-02-02 5 7
4 eric 2022-03-03 6 8
```

```
b <-data.frame(x = rep(c("tim", "eric"),2),
date = rep(c("2022-02-02","2022-03-03"),2),
a = c(1,2,5,6),
b= c(3,4,7,8)
)
```

could you help me with the syntax of the functions?

I tried:

```
reshape(a,
varying = c("tim","eric"),
v.names = c("a", "b"),
direction = "long"
)
```

```
    X       date time a b id
1.1 a 2022-02-02    1 1 2  1
2.1 b 2022-02-02    1 3 4  2
3.1 a 2022-03-03    1 5 6  3
4.1 b 2022-03-03    1 7 8  4
```

which is not doing anything good but adding useless rows.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reshaping twice in long format and then wide format:

```r
new_df <- reshape(
  a,
  idvar = c("X", "date"),
  varying = c("tim", "eric"),
  times = c("tim", "eric"),
  v.names = "value",
  timevar = "name",
  direction = "long",
  new.row.names = 1:1E5
) |> reshape(
  idvar = c("name", "date"),
  v.names = "value",
  timevar = "X",
  direction = "wide"
) 

colnames(new_df) <- gsub(
  "value\\.", "", colnames(new_df)
)

new_df
#         date name a b
# 1 2022-02-02  tim 1 3
# 3 2022-03-03  tim 5 7
# 5 2022-02-02 eric 2 4
# 7 2022-03-03 eric 6 8
```

Comment: Nice +1, try `setNames(a, c(names(a)[1:2], paste0('value.', names(a)[-(1:2)]))) |> reshape(idvar=1:2, varying=3:4, direction='long') |> reshape(idvar=2:3, timevar='X', v.names='value',  direction='wide', new.row.names=seq_len(nrow(a)))`.  What is this `new.row.names=1:1E5` about?

Comment: That argument resets `row.names` where you pick a number sufficient to accommodate the number of rows in long format.

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` approach would be to first reshape to long, then reshape to wide:

```r
library(tidyr)

a |>
  pivot_longer(-c(X, date), names_to = "x") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = X, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   date       x         a     b
#>   <chr>      <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2022-02-02 tim       1     3
#> 2 2022-02-02 eric      2     4
#> 3 2022-03-03 tim       5     7
#> 4 2022-03-03 eric      6     8
```